# Drupal, Lightbox: lightvideo adds "content/" at the beginning of Drupal paths

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, lightbox

I'm using lightvideo in lightbox2 to load my own video player.

I've just realized that lightbox is adding "content/" at the beginning of the video player path causing a "file not found" error.

In the drupal settings the correct path is set, so I'm wondering how to fix this and how to remove the initial "content/" path.

**Update**. In html code, the  element has the correct src path without "content/" but in Firebug I can see the wrong path and the video is not retrieved...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by adding "../" to the url, but it is a bit weird.

```
href.replace("videoPlayer/","../videoPlayer/")
```